# Error 404 in conslole odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In cosole get below error. Any idea whats happened here?

```
NotFound: 404: Not Found
    2018-06-12 09:59:38,732 47742 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018 09:59:38] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2018-06-12 10:00:04,722 47742 ERROR ? openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/home/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1631, in _dispatch_nodb
        func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1433, in match
```

Comment: try in a private window, and when you get the logs? I mean in which operations are you performed

Comment: @Burmesepythis-HilarAK  I'm close my eclipse and run again odoo... Now work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your odoo run under a domain? Odoo uses loongpooling with default port 8072. I guess that this port is closed. Just add reverse proxy for that port.

Comment: I'm close my eclipse and run again odoo... Now work fine :)